# NVDA doesn't read first HTML child when focusing from parent on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

When using NVDA on Firefox it fails to read the first child when focusing from a container, but it is able to read the second child.

Generic Example:

```
<div class="container" tabindex="0">
  <div class="child" aria-label="Child 1" tabindex="0">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child" aria-label="Child 2" tabindex="0">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

When `.container` is focused, and you hit tab to focus "Child 1", NVDA does not read "Child 1", but is silent. If you hit tab again NVDA reads "Child 2".

This reads correctly on Chrome with the ChromeVox addon.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGyxom

Is there some configuration that I'm missing to allow NVDA to read "Child 1" when focusing from `.container`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the markup? Like, why no semantic markup? Why have a tabindex="0" on the container when you need to read it's content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you might be describing a bug in NVDA. Here are links to two bug reports on Github describing this behaviour. It sounds like it's "intended" based on this response from the comment chain:

> This would be causing NVDa to read the entire page when it loads and therefore probably leaving focus on the final focusable node. Note that this is not really an issue for most users as they are well aware that focus will move because of the sayAll.

https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/5230
https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/3575